# Defining a new operator that performs member access

Tags: sweet.js

I'm trying to create a custom operator that is a synonym for the dot (member access) operator, such that `a>>=b` results in `a.b`.

My first attempt does not compile

```
operator >>= left 19 = (left, right) => {
    return #`${left}.${right}]`;
};
```

If i change `.` by `&&` in the return statement, then it does compile.

Since the previous approach did not work out, i tried using computed member access:

```
operator >>= left 19 = (left, right) => {
  let r = right.name.token.value; // string representation of an identifier
  let dummy = #`dummy`.get(0);
  return #`${left} [${fromStringLiteral(dummy, r)}]`;
};
```

This approach compiles for simple expressions like `a>>=b`, but not for `a>>=b.then(res => ...)`, because `right` is now a call expression: `b.then(...)`, which i don't understand since i chose a precedence of 19 for my custom operator, which is also the precedence of `[]` hence conceptually this means that my expression should be equivalent to `(a>>b).then(res => ...)` or am i wrong?